# Relative positioning on a full-width image

Tags: html, css, image, math, position

I have a background image which is naturally `1500x1062` with a `100vw width` and an `auto height`.

Now, I need to place an image on top that needs to be placed exactly `306px` from the top and `852px` from the left of the original image. But, the image needs to scale with the changing aspect-ratio since the other image is a 100% of the window width.

My head hurts and I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried converting the px to vw / vh of the second image? With one element in px and the other in view port will not work out well with changing aspect ratios.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key is to set the position top and the width of the element based on the width of the browser, because it's the width of the browser that decides the width of the image, and since the aspect ratio doesn't change, it will also decide the height of the image:

```css
.background {
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: url('http://digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/flickr/5661878892_15fba42846_o.jpg');
  background-size: 100vw;
  height: 800px;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25vw;
  top: 40vw;
  width: 1vw;
  height: 1vw;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="inner">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

fiddle for easy resizing: https://jsfiddle.net/pdn2trju/1/

Answer (score 0):

306 out of 1500 is 20.4%. Try assigning `left:20.4%` to the smaller image. Also u did not say what is the original width of the smaller image, just assign it the relative percentage for its width